# Quasar Select reacting to user input with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm have an application where my vue component has a Select control which users can select multiple items within it. I want this property to update based on what the user selects in the dropdown. However I continue to get this error when trying to set it up

`[Vue warn]: Write operation failed: computed value is readonly.`

The select is used as an input so users can add or remove multiple email addresses
Here are the trimmed down versions of the code showing the important bits...

[image]

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <q-page class="q-pa-lg justify-evenly">
      <q-select
        stack-label
        clearable
        filled
        use-input
        use-chips
        multiple
        hide-dropdown-icon
        input-debounce="0"
        new-value-mode="add-unique"
        v-model="taskRecipients"
      >
      </q-select>

  </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { Notify } from 'quasar';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'PageIndex',
  components: {},
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const taskRecipients = computed(() => root.$store.getters['app/taskRecipients']);

    return {
      taskRecipients,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make the computed property writable by adding a setter :

```
const taskRecipients = computed({

   get:() => root.$store.getters['app/taskRecipients'],

  set:(val)=>{
     root.$store.dispatch('changeTaskRecipients', val) // run the action that updates the state

  }

});
```

Comment: Is that a proper way of doing it with this? Just curious :) I'm assuming so. I'm still new to the composition api and vue projects. So I appreciate the help

Comment: Yes that's the best way when you bind store state to an input